# How to automatically update a module on a running Wildfly Server?

Tags: windows, batch-file, jboss, wildfly

I want to update a module on  my **running** WildFly10.0.0.CR4 Server with the help of a cli file on **Windows**.

For example I would need this to update the **Infinispan plugin** from version 8.0.1.Final to version 8.0.2

According to a book I am referrencing to, this could be something like

```
jboss-cli.bat --file=myupdate.cli
```

where the `myupdate.cli` file contains the code telling the server what to do (In this case, update Infinispan). I just need to know what to enter into that file - Best would be **an example with Infinispan** and a **documentation on how to write such a file** for other plugins by myself.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**:

It may also just delete the old version and install a completely new one, if this is easier.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to just update random libraries/modules. Some of them, such as Infinispan, are tightly coupled to the server.

For final releases you can use [patching](http://blog.arungupta.me/patch-wildfly-offline-online-modes-techtip29/) to update an existing server. You just need to [download](http://wildfly.org/downloads/) the patch for the container you want to update.

Comment: So that means, that it is not recommended doing so? But what about new versions of plugins that contain some kind of security fixes?

Comment: The patching should take care of that. You can simply just replace the module, but there is no guarantee it will work. I would definitely suggest manually doing this if you feel the need as it needs to be thought about and tested.